# Restore Project Settings in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

How can I restore Xcode project settings? I can't see few settings (like Targeted Device Family, iPhone OS Deployment Target, etc.) after I gave my Macbook to my friend. :(

I also saw that the info.plist file was not in the project, I recovered it via TimeMachine though, the Base SDK is also missing. :(  She messed all things up, I don't know why she went in there. Anyways, is there any way to restore the settings?

Unfortunately, the snapshot that I have is also very old. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to restore them. You can set the base sdk on the project info screen.

Project > Edit Project Settings > Base SDK, Check the same for your Target.

Comment: Nope, it's still the same. :(

Comment: Do you have any installed? I know with Xcode 3.2.5 you need to restart xcode after setting the sdk if it was not initially set. Make sure yu set it to the Latest iOS. Read my answer again above, i added the steps.

Comment: It's XCOde 3.2.4. And I have iOS Device 4.1 selected in the Base SDK option. Do I need to upgarde XCode? Will that fix this issue?

Comment: It could possibly fix the issue, but as long as you have it set in your project Settings, then it should show up in your dropdown.

Comment: Okay, as the base SDK is still not coming up, I'm currently downloading the latest release of Xcode. I'll let you know if that fixes the issue. :)

Comment: For info.plist not showing up in your project list, just simply add the file manually from the project folder (on your desktop or wherever its located).

Comment: Looks like an upgrade is required cuz I'm on 10.6.3.

Comment: Upgraded to 3.2.5 but still no luck. :(

Comment: Okay, sorted it out. I restored .xcodeproj file via TimeMachine and then I restared Xcode (as you said).

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue occurring for a specific project, or all projects?  If you create a new project, what happens?

I forget the exact syntax, but different versions of XCode handle project files slightly differently.  A new SDK (and version of XCode) couldn't read my project file right (same symptoms you explain).

In my case, there were 2 different SDK settings in the project file due to 2 separate versions of XCode editing the file (this could be very likely if you restored from backup and had upgraded SDKs in the interim).

Look for something like:

```
 SDKROOT = iphoneos4.2;
```

Or really, just look around the text that contains the build settings (all of your build settings are stored in the file in flat text) -- you may see something related to SDKs where there are 2 lines very similar right next to each other.  That'd probably be your problem.  If you don't know which to delete, try both and then re-set the setting using the interface.

Of course in any case, you should back up your project file (`project.pbxproj`) before trying any of this.

Comment: The issue is coming with a specific project only.

Comment: I updated the answer with what I did to resolve a similar problem before.